# Ruby repeated error while fetching tweets from twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

On eexecuting the following code:

```
puts @client.search("ayush").take(1)
```

the console shows the tweet but later on shows the error as:

> [2014-03-30 18:13:29] ERROR bad Request-Line
>   `:\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x00\
>   x00\x00\x00?\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00admin.$cmd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00????\x13\x00
>   \x00\x00\x10ismaster\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'. [2014-03-30 18:13:29]
>   ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was a borted by
>   the software in your host machine.
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`write'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n `<<'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396:i
>   n`_write_data'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:368:i
>   n `send_body_string'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:249:i
>   n`send_body'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:152:i
>   n `send_response'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:110:in`
>   run'
>           c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in
>   `blo ck in start_thread'

Comment: Looks like you've got an issue with your local server? Have you got a firewall set up or something?

Comment: it is not because of firewall. I just checked after turning it off. Not able to guess the possible reason.